# Adding Info into Header in email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, ssjs

Is there a way through either AMPScript or SSJS to manipulate custom content inside the email sends through the Marketing Cloud? For example, say I want to add information for 'List-Unsubscribe' into the header to allow for an automated unsubscribe process, would I be able to do this using server side code on the email?

Everything I have seen referenced in the SSJS and AMPScript functions does not seem to mention any capability of this, but thought I could ask as maybe I am missing something.

If I cannot add through scripting, what would be the best way to approach having this added in?

Comment: What do you mean by automated unsubscribe process?  AMPScript and SSJS are evaluated at send time or at each view on a landing page, once it hits the inbox or the landing page loads, it's set.

Comment: in the email header if you include information for "List-Unsubscribe" then clients will offer an unsubscribe option right alongside the spam button. This helps alleviate potential spam complaints by having them just click unsubscribe instead. - I want to be able to add this info into the header, but cannot find a place to add this in.

Comment: What email clients support this?  I've done some work with [Google Actions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/actions-overview?hl=en), but nothing that's like List-Unsubscribe.

Comment: According to this [blog post](http://www.exacttarget.com/blog/gmails-unsubscribe-function-what-you-need-to-know/), ET/SFMC emails support this already.

Comment: I know gmail has it, windows live and a couple others. I believe potentially all Outlooks may be getting this as well. Here are a couple links with more info: http://www.list-unsubscribe.com/    and another about gmail: http://marketingland.com/everything-need-know-gmails-auto-unsubscribe-75605

Comment: that is weird, because none of my headers include the list-unsubscribe information and do not have a button. Thanks for the info, I will talk to support and see what is going on.

Comment: Please post what you find out.  You've got me curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the refresh on an old post, but I thought it might be good to provide an answer here - This was an issue that was on Salesforce's end (something to do with the way their permissions were set up on the back end).  We went through around 3 months of back and forth with their developers before they realized that the permission set we had SHOULD include this, but did not. I believe we had the Sender Authentication Package with multiple IPs.  They updated it and have told me that the permissions are now in place to include the unsub header.

Comment: Yeah - thanks I completely forgot to come back to this.  I heard basically the same thing from support.  They 'magically' made it work when they 'tested' it.